# how to upload file to S3 bucket using pre-signed url in angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3

Can any one please provide example of how to upload to s3 bucket using presigned url.
I am able to generate pre singed url  but using PUT verb I am not able to upload to S3, giving below error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3-bulk-files-upload.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/File1.txt?X-Amz-Expires=599&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDAaCXVzLWVh....' from origin 'http://localhost:2020' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Thanks,
Raj4ms

Comment: Can you provide additional details about how you're attempting to upload to S3? Code snippet would be helpful, as well as knowing what library you're using to interface with AWS, if any.

Comment: Also, have you looked at [AWS's S3 CORS config documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)? Are you possibly running into [this issue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/deep-dive-into-cors-configs-on-aws-s3-how-to/)?

Comment: Header :    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders
        ({
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
        })
    }

Comment: upload(uploadFileObject: any, url: any) 
    {
        return this._http.post<any>(url, uploadFileObject, this.httpOptions);
    }

Comment: File upload to S3 using pre singed url is working from console App but not working from Angular App, tried PUT and POST but getting same error: POST https://s3-bulk-files-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/File1.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAX6G4H7OCAQRLPT3S&Expires=1589532907&x-amz-security-token=IQoJb3JpZ.....%3D 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: This is the error, I am getting, I see signature getting changed /,= are encoded                         <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAX6G4H7OCMM3RK3EP</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>PUT

Comment: Upload to S3 bucket via cloud front: I managed to solve the above issue, by using pre-singed url generated by aws-sdk (javascript configured with cloud fron endpoint) s3.getSignedUrl('putObject'...), able to upload, but my actual requirement is use multi-part uplaod using aws-sdk. So when I tried using s3obj.putObject(params, function (err, data), I  am getting error: InvalidToken: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.  Need help on this issue.

Comment: Solved this issue by generating presinged url from aws-sdk javascript and upload the file using PUT operation and added headers as headers: new HttpHeaders({
             'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'aws:kms',
             'x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id': 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:...'
        }),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by generating presinged url from aws-sdk javascript and upload the file using PUT operation, signed URL and added headers as below                           headers: new HttpHeaders({
             'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'aws:kms',
             'x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id': 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:...'
        })
as S3 bucket is configured with KMS-encryption.